# Can we post questions which are not posted in MSE but is posted in other math communities?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Can we post questions which are not posted in MSE but is posted in other math communities like in [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) or any other forums?

To be more precise: The solution is there in the other math communities but still we want to post here , so that MSE users can know this question ?

Comment: So are you trying to post it as an self-answered post?

Comment: Specifically with the relation with AOPS, some users want to bring this up for discussion in general, but we advised that they wait until next week when the current election is over and meta is more available for discussion.

Comment: At a minimum the person posting the question should note the answer in the other forum, and explain what they expect to get out of posting it here that they didn't get from the other answer. That may not be sufficient to post it here, but it's definitely necessary.